# Extracting digits to a string array by reading from file

Tags: c, file-handling, c-strings

I have a trace file where there are n lines each having the sequence read/write followed by a hex 32 bit address. Somewhat like this:

```
read  0x20000064
write 0x20000068
read  0x2000006c
```

I am not able to extract just the 32 bits address and the read/write e.g `20000064` from the file for every line. So I intend to read line by line from the file **trace** and then split every line into two sub-strings and take some action based on the sub-string.

```
    // Read the second part of sub-string and store as str1
    address = str1 & 0xffff;
    // read first part of sub-string and store as str0
    if (str0 == read)
         read_count++;
    else if (str0 == write)
         write_count++;
```

So, in short, I am stuck in splitting the string into two parts and working on them. I have tried everything ranging from `strtok()` to `fseek()`, but nothing works.

I have trace file with the contents

```
read   0x20000064
write  0x20000084
read   0x20000069
write  0x20000070
read   0x20000092
```

And the code which I have tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n;
    char *token[30];
    char delim[] = " ";
    char str[17], str2[17];
    char str3[8];
    fp = fopen("text", "r");

    while(fgets(str, 17, fp) != NULL) {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        strcpy(str2, str);
        i = 9;
        n = 8;
        while (str[i] !='\0' && n >= 0) {
            str3[j] = str2[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            n--;
        }
        str3[j] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str3);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

P.S This code works, but only for the first line, I get a Segmentation fault after that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    char *token[30];
    char delim[] = " ";
    char str[17], str2[100][17];
    char str3[17];
    int n = 9, pos = 0;
    fp = fopen("text", "r");

    while (fgets(str, 17, fp) != NULL) {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        strcpy(str2[i], str);
        if ((n + pos - 1) <= strlen(str2[i])) {
            strcpy(&str2[i][pos - 1], &str2[i][n + pos - 1]);
            printf("%s\n", str2[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Output I get:

```
20000064
Segmentation fault
```

Output I expect:

```
20000064
20000084
20000069
20000070
20000092
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the lines with `sscanf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[80];
    char command[20];
    unsigned long address;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("text", "r")) == NULL) 
        printf("cannot open text file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%19s%x", command, &address) == 2) {
            printf("command=%s, address=%x\n", command, address);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But did I miss anything here? I am still not getting the print as expected. Expected command = read, address = 0x02000064. But I am getting no print out.

Comment: @shaam: sorry, I forgot the `line` argument in the call to `sscanf()`.

Comment: Understood everything expect why you added %19s.If you could kindly explain. Thanks, working.

Comment: @shaam: `%19s` is like `%s` but will prevent `sscanf()` from attempting to store more than 19 characters into the destination array before the null terminator. Without the `19`, unexpected input would cause undefined behavior. It is important to always avoid undefined behavior.